# What to do with bounty on question which is no longer relevant?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties

I asked a question a couple of days ago. I didn't receive any answers to the question, save for a few comments.  Once the bounty period was up I placed a bounty on the question as the concern at the time was rather urgent.

I got some answers to question eventually -- as I had expected. But requirements have changed since then and the content of the question has no longer become relevant.

What can or should I do with this question? Should I award the bounty anyway, regardless of whether the question still has it's relevance?

Comment: Relevance for who? If the question can help other people, then award the bounty to the best answer tot he question.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought the same as well but I was unsure of what the protocol was. I have no need for the question anymore, but I don't know *who* to award the bounty to because the result of the answer isn't relevant to me.

Comment: Well, the fact is that your bounty is gone. And if there is an answer which is correct and worth the bounty under old circumstances of question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you post a question, the question is yours, but not yours anymore. That's why you cannot delete it too easily, especially if it has answers, and that's why if you do it a lot of times, you get question banned.

In the first case, you'd be throwing away the work of users who used their time to write answers to help you.

Even if your question is not "relevant" to you anymore, award the bounty/accept the answer that solved the problem highlighted in the question. If someone else comes to your question, this will help them.

This is what I meant by saying that *"the question is yours, but not yours anymore"*: it's for anybody that faces the same problem.

Comment: Even more: before posting a question, it must have some relevance for future visitors too. Otherwise it has no place in [libraries of high-quality questions and answers](http://stackexchange.com/about).