# Bounty question no longer relevent to OP

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, bounties

I have a bountied question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559230/sys-platform-is-not-defined-x64-windows/). I can no longer test the validity of any answers, because I have moved back to 32 bit Python, and the question deals with 64 bit Python. Anyway, trust me that I am no longer able to test these answers.

I have read [this related meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97203/policy-on-accepting-answer-after-question-is-no-longer-relevant-to-original-post), but that does not talk at all about bounties.

My dilemma is the following:

None of the answers I have received help me, and so if I were to just sit and do nothing (as the SO meta post implies), the first poster would get rewarded for giving an unhelpful answer, which in my mind goes against the point of the bounty/points system.

It would be more just for the community to choose (via upvotes) the best answer.

What should I do in the spirit of the points system?

EDIT: Wait a second! My question on SO is still relevant to others, so this is a different question, unlike in the "duplicate" you linked to. Motion to re-open. In the question marked as "duplicate" the OP says that his question is no longer relevant to him, and implies anyone else. My question is about a relevant question which I can no longer test.

EDIT2: I want to clear something up. @James said in the comments `You're essentially asking what to do with a bounty when there are no good answers`. I do not think so. No, actually I am asking what to do when I cannot **test** any of the answers, there is a difference. Regardless of whether or not better answers arrive (which would be great), **I cannot test if the answers actually work or are better**. I am not worried about not getting a solution to my problem, I am worried about being unable to evaluate it in the first place. For all I know the next answers could make the problem worse. So the question is about how I should deal with the points if I don't feel qualified dishing them out. This is why PythonMaster's answer of "choose the one most likely to work" is about as good as it gets. It is also why I am accepting his answer.

Comment: related quote `Even if your question is not "relevant" to you anymore, award the bounty/accept the answer that solved the problem highlighted in the question.  ` from [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139015/what-should-i-do-with-a-bounty-on-a-question-which-is-no-longer-relevant). However, there is no answer that answers the question in my bounty.

Comment: Oh, that's just 50 points. ***Forget.***

Comment: Hey, that is like 1/8th of my total points, it is important to me.

Comment: You won't get the bounty back...

Comment: I know that. I guess this is important for precedent. I will probably just forget, unless someone else comes up with a good answer.

Comment: Did you try the python chat room already to get better answers?

Comment: Hmm... I have never really used the chat room. I guess I'll give it a try in a little while.

Comment: I would bide your time, it may well get a better answer that you're comfortable awarding the bounty to yet.  And it may even help you in the future if you try a 64 bit install again.  It got mentioned in the sopython chat room, which might attract a couple of answers, depending who's around.

Comment: This is a dupe of many other questions. You're essentially asking what to do with a bounty when there are no good answers, and/or when an answer will get auto awarded bounty which you feel is not worthy. etc, etc. There is nothing new to add to your question which hasn't been asked before, the bounty works as it does. If you feel the bounty system could be improved or changed in some way, feel free to raise a feature request with the proposed changes :)

Comment: Also, there are 6 days to go on the bounty, what's the current panic? Answers on featured  questions often come later on -  day 5 or 6.

Comment: @James, `You're essentially asking what to do with a bounty when there are no good answers`. No, actually I am asking what to do when I cannot __test__ any of the answers, there is a difference. If I am unable to test the answers, then how can I evaluate what a "good" or "bad" answer is. This has nothing to do with a __lack__ of answers, it is a lack of answers that I can evaluate.

Comment: So you cannot test the answers because you changed your scope - what are you suggesting is done about it? "*What should I do in the spirit of the points system?*" chalk it up to experience/one of those things, and move on :) Either let the system decide who gets the bounty, or if you feel one of the answers deserves your rep for some reason manually award it. i.e. an answer being good based on the quality and info etc

Comment: @James, that is why I am choosing PythonMaster's answer, because he basically said that. Thanks though. :)

Comment: It can be a tough choice sometimes. I had a 100 bounty here on MSE, and one answer which was useful but in no way answered my question at all. I gave the bounty because it was a good answer. And while didn't get me what "I" wanted, someone took time to respond with something useful, and not awarding it at all is a waste of rep - no-one wins. (of course I won't manually award to poor or non-helpful answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, but the bounty also attracted attention and possibly more answers.

People try to fix your problem and they don't work but they might help others. The thing is, if the grace period passes and there is an answer that exceeds all other answers in all other requirements, it will automatically award it half the bounty. This is like as you said, the community awarding the bounty. Well, the answer might deserve it as it is ***the best possible answer to your question*** out of all the other answers. And it helps the others users more than any other than any other competing answer.

Your bounty of course, will not be able to be retracted. In the spirits of the points system, award the bounty to the answer ***most likely*** to answer your question(usually the highest upvotes answer) or the answer that ***helped you the most in trying to solve your problem***. If you can't decide and seemingly no answer "deserves" your bounty in your opinion, let the community "award" it for you. At least you didn't spend all that rep for nothing! :)

So either award it to the most deserving answer(explained in above paragraph) or let the community award it(explained in the second paragraph). I hope this helps you!

Comment: Makes sense. I want to wait to see some other opinions, but I agree with your logic.

Comment: You could also ask others to test the resulting answers for you, or trust when someone said that it worked for them.